# gradle task description not showing

Tags: gradle

I am new to Gradle.
I am studying and reading of "Adding Description to a Task" section in

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_tasks.htm

and I wrote a code like below:

```
task a << {
    description 'haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    println "hello world"
}
```

after that, I run the build script file with the command in which the build.gradle file is stored:

```
gradle -q a
```

And I got the message "hello wrold" only.

How do I get the description message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<` operator defines a `doLast` block (an action to be executed with the task). Description is specific to the task rather than the action:

```
task a {
    description 'some description'
    doLast {
        println 'hello world'
    }
}
```

You can see the description by executing `./gradlew :tasks --all`:

```
[...]
Other tasks
-----------
a - some description
[...]
```

By the way `<<` operator has been deprecated for a while now and will be removed in Gradle 5.0. This entire tutorial seems to be pretty badly dated (looks like Gradle 2.x-ish), I'd recommend using the official documentation (even if it is a bit hard to navigage)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Now I can see the description message! and I got to know that I should read official documentation.